# Join with on duplicate not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query that looks like this:

```
$DB->query("INSERT INTO table (
  SELECT s.value1, s.value2, s.value3, t.value1, u.value1, u.value2, u.value3, u.value4
  FROM aTable AS s
  LEFT JOIN aTable2 AS u ON u.uID = s.uid 
  WHERE u.spent < ". $needed ."
  GROUP BY s.uid, s.fid ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  value1 = VALUES(u.value1), 
  value2 = VALUES(u.value2), 
  value3 = VALUES(u.value3), 
  value4 = VALUES(u.value4);
");
```

However this returns the error:

> Unknown column 'u.value1' in 'field list'

Please note that this is the first time I'm working with MySQL at this level, so I have no idea how the `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` function works...

What i intent to do with the table is like a cache, because the infromation is fetched from some very large table

Comment: See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for the correct syntax.

Comment: I've looked at the documentation, but I simply cannot understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values statement refers to the values in the column list for the `insert`.  You don't have these listed, but a guess is:

```
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  value1 = VALUES(value1), 
  value2 = VALUES(value2), 
  value3 = VALUES(value3), 
  value4 = VALUES(value4);
```

Comment: I tried that, but i ended up with alot of random numbers that i have no idea where came from

Comment: @user2674081 . . . I suspect that you have a different problem where there are multiple matches in the join causing the duplicates.  Do you really intend to aggregate by both keys in the `group by`?

Comment: To be honest the query is stithced together by different other quries that i found around the site that did part of the functions i needed. Not even sure that group by does.

Comment: What i intent to do with the table is like a cache, because the infromation is fetched from some very large tables

Comment: @user2674081 . . . I think you should delete this question and ask another question about how to solve the problem you really need to solve.  Your problem is not a syntax error in the above query.

Comment: Again, I have no clue what the problem is. This MySQL is making very little sense to me, never digged this deep into it.